# find users who can visit each other on same available time( time overlapping)

Tags: php, arrays, time

I want to write a function which must find the overlapping time that two or more people can visit each other at the available time. Let me explain:

Here's is my data:

```
$availability = [
    [
        ["8:30", "12:00"],
        ["17:00", "22:00"]
    ],
    [
        ["5:00", "11:15"],
        ["14:25", "20:05"]
    ]
];
```

and I want this result:

```
RESULT:
[
    ('8:30', '11:15'),
    ('17:00', '20:05')
]
```

**My problem** is that i can only get the **latest result** `('17:00', '20:05')` not the first one.
blank result:

```
$availability = [
    [
        ["8:30", "12:00"],
        ["17:00", "22:00"]
    ],
    [
        ["5:00", "11:15"],
        ["14:25", "20:05"]
    ]
];
$periods = [];
while (true) {
    $start = array_reduce($availability, function ($carry, $ranges) {
        $start = array_reduce($ranges, function ($carry, $range) {
            return !$carry ? $range[0] : min($range[0], $carry);
        });
        return !$carry ? $start : max($start, $carry);
    });
    $matching_ranges = array_filter(array_map(function ($ranges) use ($start) {
        return current(array_filter($ranges, function ($range) use ($start) {
            return $range[0] <= $start && $range[1] >= $start;
        }));
    }, $availability));
    if (count($matching_ranges) < count($availability)) {
        break;
    }
    $end = array_reduce($matching_ranges, function ($carry, $range) {
        return !$carry ? $range[1] : min($range[1], $carry);
    });
    $periods[] = [$start, $end];
    array_walk($availability, function (&$ranges) use ($end) {
        $ranges = array_filter($ranges, function ($range) use ($end) {
            return $range[1] > $end;
        });
    });
}

// Output the answer in the specified format.
foreach ($periods as $period) {
    echo "$period[0] -> $period[1]\n";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: you should probably be using actual `DateTime` values (of some description) not just text/string times. So let's fix that:

```
// Iterate over array converting the referenced &$time to a DateTime object
array_walk_recursive($availability, function(&$time){
    $time = new DateTime($time);
});
```

Now we need to be able to define an over lap in simple terms:

```
A-------------------B
           C---------------D

Rules:
  1. Time A MUST be before Time D
  2. Time B MUST be after time C
```

Once we know that there is an over lap we can use PHP's `min` and `max` functions to  determine the correct start/end times of the overlap:

```
Start: max(A, C) // C
End:   min(B,D)  // B
```

From here I've had to make a few assumptions...

1. Each sub array is an individual's/user's availability. For example:

   ```
    $availability = [
            "Dave" => [
                ["8:30", "12:00"],
                ["17:00", "22:00"]
            ],
            "Terry" => [
                ["5:00", "11:15"],
                ["14:25", "20:05"]
            ],
            "Louise" => [
                ["13:00", "14:15"],
                ["18:25", "19:05"]
            ]
        ];
   ```
2. You want to match every overlap between any two people. So in the above example you'd get:

   ```
    "Timeslot: 08:30 to 11:15"
    "Timeslot: 17:00 to 20:05"
    "Timeslot: 18:25 to 19:05"
   ```

The solution then is to loop over every *person* and check their availability against every other person -> requiring a series of nested `foreach` loops. If there's a match then store it and, finally, output removing any duplicates...

```
$matchedTimes = [];

foreach ($availability as $key => $userOneAvailability){

    $userAvailibility = $availability;

    unset($userAvailibility[$key]);

    foreach ($userOneAvailability as $userOneTimeSlot) {
        foreach ($userAvailibility as $userTwoAvailability) {
            foreach ($userTwoAvailability as $userTwoTimeSlot) {
                if (
                    $userOneTimeSlot[0] < $userTwoTimeSlot[1] 
                    && $userOneTimeSlot[1] > $userTwoTimeSlot[0]
                ) {
                    $matchedTimes[] =
                        "Timeslot: ".
                        max($userOneTimeSlot[0], $userTwoTimeSlot[0])->format("H:i").
                        " to ".
                        min($userOneTimeSlot[1], $userTwoTimeSlot[1])->format("H:i");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

var_dump(array_unique($matchedTimes));
```

Of course this only outputs the textual representation but you could modify the `if` block to do pretty much anything you need it to do.

---

If it doesn't matter who is available and you're simply interested when two or more people are free perhaps you could try something like:

```
$timeArray = [];

function fillTimeArray($startTime, $endTime, &$outputArray) {
    list($startHour, $startMinute) = explode(":", $startTime);
    list($endHour, $endMinute)     = explode(":", $endTime);

    for($h = (int) $startHour; $h <= (int) $endHour; $h++) {
        $minuteOffsetStart = $h == $startHour ? (int) $startMinute : 0;
        $minuteOffsetEnd   = $h == $endHour   ? (int) $endMinute   : 59;

        for ($m = $minuteOffsetStart; $m <= $minuteOffsetEnd; $m++) {
            $outputArray[$h . "." . $m] = ($outputArray[$h . "." . $m] ?? 0) + 1;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($availability as $user) {
    foreach ($user as $timeSlot) {
        fillTimeArray($timeSlot[0], $timeSlot[1], $timeArray);
    }
}

$timeArray = array_filter($timeArray, function($a){ return $a > 1;});
```

The above will give you an array (`$timeArray`) of time slots with how many people are free at those times... In the format:

```
Array
(
    [8.30] => 2
    [8.31] => 2
    [8.32] => 2
    [8.33] => 2
    ...
    [11.14] => 2
    [11.15] => 2
);
```

If you want to narrow it down you can use the following code to get start and end time for time slots.

```
$timeSlots = [];

foreach ($timeArray as $key => $count) {
    list ($hour, $minute) = explode(".", $key);

    if ( !($hour == $lastHour && $minute = $lastMinute + 1) && !($hour == $lastHour + 1 && $minute == 0 && $lastMinute == 59) ) {
        $startTime = $hour . "." . $minute;
    }

    $timeSlots[$startTime] = $hour . "." . $minute;

    $lastHour = $hour;
    $lastMinute = $minute;
}

print_r($timeSlots);
```

This gives you an array in the format `[startTime] => endTime`. But doesn't take into account who is free etc. simply that 2 or more people are free at that time.

```
Array
(
    [8.30] => 11.15
    [17.0] => 20.5
)
```

You could, perhaps, extend this code by storing an array of *users* which are free instead of just the number of them. Which should be simple enough?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your time. Still, it doesn't show the first result. It doesn't show `('8:30', '11:15'),` as a first available time. And for performance, it has taken a lot of resources as 4 nested `foreach` loops. Is anyway available to write it with array functions to have a better performance on large data?

Comment: It does show the first time of `08.30 to 11:15`? Assuming I'm correct and each sub array is an _individual_ then I'm not really sure how you intend to do this without looping over the data several times? Also, array functions are effectively just loops and you're unlikely to save much time switching between the two.